# I do not understand this assembly snippet, I just came across

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I came across the following assembly code, but I do not understand it.

```
hang:
  jmp hang
  times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

Can anyone please explain me, what is happening ?

Answer (score 2):

This will cause your program to hang by going into an infinite loop, because `jmp hang` jumps to itself.

Comment: The `times` line just pads the file to 512 bytes. Often you'll see `times 510 - ($-$$) db 0` followed by `db 55`, `db 0AAh` - the "boot signature". The `$` means (roughly) "here" - the current location in the assembly. The `$$` means "beginning of section", so `($-$$)` means "length of code, so far". As Nathan points out, you usually want a `jmp hang` first. It is not intended that the `times` line is executed!

Comment: This makes me remember of the good'ol days of mbr programming :)

Answer (score 1):

That code is used to fill the remaining program with 0 (which, if im not mistaken, is something like an 'add' instruction).
It is usually used in boot code in order to put the mbr signature at the end, and as so, in terms of "code", it is not supposed to be executed.

In conclusion:

- That does not perform a halt.
- It is used to fill the program file with '00' until it reaches 512byte (in the assembler's output file! It does nothing in runtime!)
- To halt your program do something like:

  ```
  halt:
    jmp halt
  ```

Comment: You probably want an actual `hlt` instruction in there. This "halts" the CPU, but only until an interrupt occurs. This lets the CPU cool off a bit. If there's a `cli` in there, an interrupt should never occur... but an NMI (non-maskable interrupt) still could, so we still want the `jmp halt` as Gallium Nitride shows.